# Why does pack of a same Frame at diffrent lines output diffrent things?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to print out 3 buttons as tiles side by side , so when I write this code with pack alongside frame creation 
I get this output:

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkqlX.png)

When I pack frame afterwards I get this output

[image]

I don't understand this please explain

CODE 1

```
class mainpage:
  def __init__(self,master):
    mainpage=Frame(master,width=100, height=100).pack(pady=50)
    self.im=Image.open("g.png")
    self.ph=ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.im)
    b1=Button(mainpage,image=self.ph).pack(side=LEFT,padx=50)
    b2=Button(mainpage,image=self.ph).pack(side=LEFT,padx=50)
    b3=Button(mainpage,image=self.ph).pack(side=LEFT,padx=50)
 root = Tk()
 m=mainpage(root)
 root.mainloop()
```

CODE 2

```
class mainpage:


def __init__(self,master):
    mainpage=Frame(master,width=100, height=100).pack(pady=50)
    self.im=Image.open("g.png")
    self.ph=ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.im)
    b1=Button(mainpage,image=self.ph).pack(side=LEFT,padx=50)
    b2=Button(mainpage,image=self.ph).pack(side=LEFT,padx=50)
    b3=Button(mainpage,image=self.ph).pack(side=LEFT,padx=50)
    mainpage.pack(pady=50)
root = Tk()
m=mainpage(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Both blocks of code have errors, so I don't see how it's possible for either one to generate the image you give in your question.

Comment: This is part of the code and the indentation was affected while copying , rest assured it works fine and if you have the answer to why it generates 2 different outputs do let me know.

Comment: If I can't run it, I can't debug it. We can't see the code on your computer, and there's nothing in stackoverflow that prevents the proper formatting of code.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is because the order that you call `pack` matters. `pack` places things in remaining space. Once you've packed something along one of the sides of a window, it removes some of the remaining space.

The problem in your code is that you're putting everything in the root window. That is because of this line of code:

```
mainpage=Frame(master,width=100, height=100).pack(pady=50)
```

It is setting `mainpage` to `None`. Thus, when you do `Button(mainpage, ...)` it is the same as `Button(None, ...)` which places the button in the root window.

I'm assuming your intent is to put the buttons inside `mainpage` to do that, you must separate the creation of `mainpage` from the layout of `mainpage`:

```
mainpage=Frame(master,width=100, height=100)
mainpage.pack(pady=50)
```